# jQuery .click(function(){} "Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

### It's been answered.

javascript.js

```
var jQuery     = require('jquery');
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);

var cardsArr;

function init(){
 cardsArr = [
 'cards/2.png',
 'cards/3.png',
 'cards/4.png',
 'cards/5.png',
 'cards/6.png',
 'cards/7.png',
 'cards/8.png',
 'cards/9.png',
 'cards/10.png',
 'cards/J.png',
 'cards/Q.png',
 'cards/K.png',
 'cards/A.png'
 ];
}

function cardMath(){
 var oneCard = cardsArr[(Math.random() * cardsArr.length)|0];
 return oneCard;
};

function singleCard(){
 $("#singleCard").remove();
 $("#single").append($('<div id="singleCard"><img class="rounded" src="/' + 
 cardMath() + '"/></div>').hide().fadeIn(750));
}
```

header.ejs

```
<body onLoad="init()">
```

---

I created a card shuffler button, that when clicked, will load a local card image and display it. The button has a jQuery click function attached and it calls the functions, which shuffles the array data, in javascript.js file. It seems that the click function isn't reading the cards array, so "cardsArr.length" comes up as "length" undefined.

```
javascript.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
 at cardMath (javascript.js:38)
 at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):45)
 at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
 at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

index.ejs

```
<% include ./partials/header %>
<div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <button name="oneCard" id="oneCard" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" placeholder="One Card">
                        Random Card</button>
                        <script>
                            $("#oneCard").click(function(){
                                return singleCard();
                            });
                        </script>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6" id="multiple">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row multiple" id="secondRow">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6" id="single">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

Yet, if I copy and paste the javascript.js code into Chrome Console and run cardOutput(), it will successfully read the array so the images will load and the button will work when clicked, at least until page refresh.  How do I fix this?

javascript.js

```
var express    = require('express'),
jQuery     = require('jquery'),
bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);

var cardsArr =
 [
 'cards/2.png',
 'cards/3.png',
 'cards/4.png',
 'cards/5.png',
 'cards/6.png',
 'cards/7.png',
 'cards/8.png',
 'cards/9.png',
 'cards/10.png',
 'cards/J.png',
 'cards/Q.png',
 'cards/K.png',
 'cards/A.png'
 ];

function cardMath(){
 var oneCard = cardsArr[(Math.random() * cardsArr.length)|0];
 return oneCard;
};

function singleCard(){
 if(document.getElementById("singleCard") === true && 
 document.getElementsByClassName("shuffledCards") === true){
    $("#single").append($('<div id="singleCard"><img class="rounded" src="/'+ cardMath() + '"/></div>').hide().fadeIn(750));
} else {
    $("#singleCard").remove();
    $("#single").append($('<div id="singleCard"><img class="rounded" src="/' + cardMath() + '"/></div>').hide().fadeIn(750));
 }
}

function cardOutput(){
 singleCard();
}
```

EDIT

header.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/landing.css">
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylesheets/javascript.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Something is clearly wrong here. `javascript.js` looks like a Node.js script, but at the same time you claim it's executed on the client-side too. Can you show how it's included in HTML?

Comment: Something is causing `cardsArr` to become undefined, the error is happening on `cardsArr.length`.

Comment: It is a node.js script, and I included the HTML.

Comment: What in tarnation is going on here?